# DCM4CHEE fail to send DICOM images

Tags: windows

I am using DCM4CHEE library to send DICOM image to a PACS.
Usually I do not have any error.

But a few weeks ago,I had an error and I can not understand why this is failing.

I use this

```
dcmsnd DCM4CHEE@X.X.X.X:P path/to/my/dicom
```

X.X.X.X being the address of the server and P the port to use

The error is the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is sending the PACS that is receiving the images. In some cases it has to do with the "MaximumValueLength". In DCH4CHEE you can assign a larger value and try again.

**Source:** http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part07/sect_C.5.html#sect_C.5.21

Comment: Larger value of what? I do not really understand, what should I do? Edit my command to send? Or edit the PACS config to accept larger fields?

Comment: If you are using DCM4CHEE library, I suppose that other side you have a PACS Server that receive the transferences. This error: 0110H it is defined for the standard when there a error in the transfer. In this case could be the size each dicom image, is for this reason that you can find in the PACS that receive a settings like "MaximumValueLength" and change the value to a more bigger, this based in your image in the question.